# How to print table with image using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0tc9hb7u/1/)
 print table but barcode column showing blank. How can i print table with barcode image?

Sample Javascript code like that

```
function printData()
{
   var divToPrint=document.getElementById("printTable");
   newWin= window.open("");
   newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
   newWin.print();
   newWin.close();
}

$('button').on('click',function(){
printData();
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/0tc9hb7u/12/

First you need to get all images in your new window

```
var images = newWin.document.getElementsByTagName("img");
```

Then you should call `newWin.print()` only when all images are loaded.

```
var imagesLoaded = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var image = images[i];
    var img = new Image(); 

    img.onload = function () {
        imagesLoaded++;
        // Ok, image was loaded, let's check if it was the last image to load
        if (imagesLoaded === images.length) {
            newWin.print();
        }
    }
    var oneSrc = image.getAttribute('src');

    img.src = oneSrc;
};
```

Comment: Updated my answer with `print` call when image is loaded ;)

Comment: Thank you :) it is worked for me. I've question i added an image like watermark on jsfiddle. But it is not showing can you check it  http://jsfiddle.net/0tc9hb7u/9/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0tc9hb7u/10/
The problem was that you add only table to print page (without watermark)

Comment: Thank you for answer. Yes i forgot add in printTable :) But watermark is not looking  as watermark on print preview/print out watermark image on top table. Do you have any idea for the watermark? @Arūnas Smaliukas

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0tc9hb7u/12/
Your styles was not in printTable either. Moreover I have updated script to wait until ALL images are loaded and then show print dialog.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I think it is more accurate than `setTimeout`:
1) if all images will load very quickly, with timeout you will have to wait one second for dialog to show
2) if images will load slower than one second, print dialog will show after 1 sec but it will be without all images

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `"newWin"` as `newWin` `name` property ; utilizing `setTimeout` to delay calling `.print()` until images loaded in newly opened `window`

```
function printData() {
    var divToPrint = document.getElementById("printTable");
    newWin = window.open("", "newWin");
    newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
    setTimeout(function () {
        newWin.print();
    }, 1000)
    // newWin.close();
}

$('button').on('click', function () {
    printData();
})
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0tc9hb7u/4/